# AJAX UpdatePanel triggers in different contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a problem with UpdatePanel Triggers. I'm using a Master Page, which has five content area's in it.

In my Default.aspx file in one content area I have a RadioButtonList(AutoPostBack=true), in other content I have an UpdatePanel.

I've tried to add a trigger to this UpdatePanel but no method(listed below) I've tried works?

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rblSize" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>


AsyncPostBackTrigger tr1 = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
tr1.ControlID = rblSize.UniqueID;/"rblSize";
tr1.EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged";
upObrazki.Triggers.Add(tr1);
```

When I use conditional update I still see the refreshing of page.

Comment: Is the RadioButtonList also in an UpdatePanel? I believe all elements that you want to do partial postbacks should be inside one

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UpdatePanel's UpdateMode property to `UpdateMode="Conditional"`.

Then in your SelectedIndexChanged event you can trigger the UpdatePanel by calling:

```
upObrazki.Update();
```